# passing parameters to url angularjs and ionic

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and ionic. I have created an application which gets posts from wordpress website (with rest api).
I have 2 files index.html and post.html
In index.html there are the lists of the posts. What i want is create a link
ex:    `<a href="{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a>`
and when i click this link it opens post.html and displays `{{post.content.rendered}}`
I have managed to do all this, but i dont know how to pass the parameter post.id to the file post.html in order to display the content of that post.

Please need help
Thank You

Comment: Is this a single-page app, or does the page refresh/update?

Comment: index.html refreshes and updates, post.html acts like a template for displaying the content of the post (clicked in index.html)

Comment: Bummer. It's all so easy with a SPA. Maybe consider refactoring to use ngRoute or ui.router with dynamic views.

Comment: :) any code example just to begin with, because i have no idea what you are talking about :)

Comment: Lots of documentation available for those. AngularJS is most commonly used for single-page apps, so there are countless examples available. I'm surprised that anyone working with Angular hasn't become familiar.

Comment: ok i'll google it. how can i achieve this in a single page app?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: i dont get, i have followed the tutorial and it throws this error XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///G:/IONIC/tabbedSlideBox/post.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in the comments thread. Edit your original post, or delete it and start fresh with a specific question. SO isn't a discussion forum. Read the help pages for more.